# Как привести списки к одному общему виду?

Tags: c#, list

Есть два списка

```
List<string> lst1 = new List<string>(){"Бренд:Zara","Вес:40гр","Размер:20*20*20"};
List<string> lst2 = new List<string>(){"Бренд:Mario Muzi","Вес:1230гр","Фасовка:1",};
```

Я в итоге хочу объединть оба списка, чтобы вывести потом в Excell. Единственная проблема - привести оба списка в единый формат, чтобы название колонок было одно. В итоге должно получиться. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а почему бы не использовать класс, который описывает данную таблицу и использовать список объектов этого класса ? если переменная класса = null, то ячейка должна быть пустой

Comment: Я изначально не знаю сколько у меня полей будет, вот в этом проблема.

Comment: а как Вы получаете строку(*"Бренд:Zara","Вес:40гр","Размер:20*20*20"*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<string> lst1 = new List<string>() { "Бренд:Zara", "Вес:40гр", "Размер:20*20*20" };
List<string> lst2 = new List<string>() { "Бренд:Mario Muzi", "Вес:1230гр", "Фасовка:1", };
List<string> titles = new List<string>();
        lst1.ForEach(s => titles.Add(s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(":", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))));
        lst2.ForEach(s => titles.Add(s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(":", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))));
        titles = titles.Distinct().ToList();
        //print titles ....
        titles.ForEach(t => Console.Write(t + "\t"));
        Console.WriteLine();
        //For lst 1
        titles.ForEach(t =>
        {
            var str =
                lst1.Where(s => s.Contains(t))
                    .Select(s => s.Substring(t.Length+1))
                    .FirstOrDefault();
            Console.Write(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)?"--\t":str+"\t");
        });
        Console.WriteLine();
        //for lst2
        //....
```

Comment: А зачем везде `.ForEach`? Чем `titles.ForEach(t => Console.Write(t + "\t"));` лучше, чем `foreach (var t in titles) Console.Write(t + "\t");`?

Comment: @ VladD Просто предпочитаю в 1 строку. Компилятор потом развернет в цикл

Comment: Ну, в одну строку можно и так и так.

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно создать класс описывающий товар, затем объединять списки например так:

```
List<Product> lst1 = new List<Product>() { new Product() { Brand = "Zara", Weight = 40, Size = "20*20*20" } };
List<Product> lst2 = new List<Product>() { new Product() { Brand = "Mario Muzi", Weight = 1230, Pre_Packing = 1 } };

List<Product> allList = lst1.Concat(lst2).ToList();
```

класс товара:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public int Pre_Packing { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Я изначально не знаю сколько у меня полей будет, вот в этом проблема.

Comment: @Radzhab: Это серьёзное уточнение. Имеет смысл дополнить вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Мой вариант будет аналогичен предложению от @Leonid Malyshev. 
Для хранения объединённой информации мне понадобится вспомогательный следующий класс:

```
class MergedEntityInfo
{
    public string Name;
    public string Value1;
    public string Value2;
}
```

Теперь предположим, что формат описания свойства "<имя>:<значение>" всегда соблюдается для обоих списков, тогда проанализируем информацию хранящуюся в первом списке:

```
var mergedEntityInfoMap = (from entityDescription in lst1
                                       let info = entityDescription.Split(':').ToArray()
                                       let entity = new MergedEntityInfo { Name = info[0], Value1 = info[1] }
                                       select entity)
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Name);
```

Далее пройдёмся по второму списку и дополним информацию в `mergedEntityInfoMap`:

```
foreach (var info in lst2.Select(x => x.Split(':').ToArray()))
            {
                MergedEntityInfo mergedEntityInfo;
                if (mergedEntityInfoMap.TryGetValue(info[0], out mergedEntityInfo))
                {
                    mergedEntityInfo.Value2 = info[1];
                }
                else
                {
                    mergedEntityInfoMap[info[0]] = new MergedEntityInfo { Name = info[0], Value2 = info[1] };
                }
            }
```

Вот и всё, в `mergedEntityInfo`содержится объединённая информация.